# Automate Windows administration tasks

Tags: powershell, graphical-user-interface, development

I'm diving headfirst into PowerShell (by no means an expert yet) and am looking to build a GUI to automate Windows admin tasks, both for the deskop and server side.  I know there are third-party tools and whatnot available as free downloads, but I'm not interested in those, as my main objective is to learn by doing. I really want to build my own GUI as opposed to downloading or purchasing another tool so I can create something which encompasses most of the items I would need without all the extra fluff.

For what it's worth, onto the question:

I'm looking at products (Sapien PowerShell Studio is one) for this project.  For those with experience with it, do you feel this is worth the money and time/effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used PowerShell studio and can recommend it, but I have no other product to compare it to as it's the only software of it's kind I've used.  It's pretty solid and does what I need it to do.

Whether this project and/or the software will be worth your money, time and effort is subjective, and is based on your needs and budget.

Comment: Thank you bentek. I don't necessarily have a hard budget.  This is more of a personal project versus a job requirement.  I think I will give it a go and see how it turns out.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck to you with the tool building project.